# tex4ht duplicates TOC in two columns in TL 2023 but OK in TL 2022. What changed?

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht

I found a problem in TL 2023 on same document and same command, where now tex4ht duplicates the TOC in two columns instead of spreading the TOC over the two columns as it always did before.

Same document, same command.  So something changed. The question is how to make it behave as it did in TL 2022? Do I need to change something in the command or in the latex?

I have document where in HTML only, I wanted to make the TOC spread over 2 columns because it is very long so I am using `multicol` package. This has been working ok for many years.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\title{my book}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\ifdefined\HCode 
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{section}
\fi 

\ifdefined\HCode 
\begin{multicols}{2}
{
\tableofcontents
}
\end{multicols}
\else 
\tableofcontents
\fi 

\section{section 1}
text
\section{section 2}
text
\section{section 3}
text
\section{section 4}
text
\section{section 5}
text
\section{section 6}
text

\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
make4ht -ulm default -a warning main.tex 'mathjax,htm,fn-in,0,notoc*,p-width,cut-fullname'
```

This is the output on a Linux running TL 2023

[image]

This is the output on a Linux still running  TL 2022

[image]

Reference: [entry](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?606) at tex4ht tracking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this bug was introduced when I fixed [another issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676531/2891). I will fix that in TeX4ht sources. In the meantime, try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\pend:def\tableofcontents{\gdef\:StartSec{\au:StartSec}}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

[image]